# Undefined variable: POST - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a form like this:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="script/gen.php?postData">
            <table width="450px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="customer">Customer:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input  type="text" name="customer" maxlength="50" size="30">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"">
                        <label for="nol">Number of licences: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input type="text" name="nol" maxlength="50" size="30">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" id="submit" action="script/gen.php">
                            <input type="button" onClick="getKey()"; value="Generate key"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>



                <div id="innhold">
                            <h4>Licence Key: </h>
                </div>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
```

The codelines of interest is:

```
<input type="text" name="nol" maxlength="50" size="30">
```

and

```
<input  type="text" name="customer" maxlength="50" size="30">
```

I try to write this information to a database like this:

```
function postData($key1) {
//just to check if the key is equal to the one thats posted to the user
//echo '<h5>From postData' . $key1 . '</h5>';
/*echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("The order has been submitted successfully");
location = "/Webpanel/index.html";
</script>';*/

$customerVar = $POST['customer'];
$nolVar = $POST['nol'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("licencedatabase");

$query_add = "INSERT INTO licence (`customer_name`,`licence_count`) VALUES ('$customerVar','$nolVar')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close();
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Undefined variable: POST
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using notepad++ and WAMP for testing locally and Firebug plugin for chrome.

Comment: a very quick and simple search on google would have given you the answer immediately...

Comment: all mysql_* functions are deprecated, as shown on [every page of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php): Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) not `$POST`.

```
$customerVar = $_POST['customer'];
$nolVar = $_POST['nol'];
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because it's called `$_POST`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$_POST` instead of `$POST`

Answer (score 2):

to access the superglobal POST use `$_POST` not `$POST`

Answer (score 1):

All PHP superglobals (such as those for GET and POST) are prefixed with an underscore, so: `$POST` should be `$_POST`.

Have a look here for more information about the available superglobals in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$_POST` instead of `$POST`

Check following example:

The predefined `$_POST` variable is used to collect values from a form sent with `method="post"`.

Information sent from a form with the POST method is invisible to others and has no limits on the amount of information to send.

**Example:**

```
<form action="submitform.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    Age:  <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user clicks the `"Submit"` button, the URL will look like this: http://localhost/submitform.php

The `"submitform.php"` file can now use the `$_POST` variable to collect form data (the names of the form fields will automatically be the keys in the `$_POST` array):

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?>  years old.
```

might you will understand clearly.